# How to call a local file as the source for Webview in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I want to display the content of my 'html file' in the webview

```
import HTML_FILE from '../screens/imagecropper.html';

<WebView
     originWhitelist={['*']}
     source={HTML_FILE}
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
/>
```

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Moodle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-image-editor/latest/tui-image-editor.css">
    <script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-image-editor/latest/tui-image-editor.js"></script>
    <h1>Homepage Headline</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected result is
   Homepage Headline

This is a paragraph.

But is just read the content and display the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Moodle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-image-editor/latest/tui-image-editor.css">
    <script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-image-editor/latest/tui-image-editor.js"></script>
    <h1>Homepage Headline</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in this way

- for android : paste your html file in assets folder than you can get it by this way

  `source={{uri:'file:///android_asset/webpage.html'}}`
- for iOS make a folder in iOS and add  files in it. and get it like that

  `source={{uri:'./htmls/webpage.html'}}`